# WebHelpers FileUpload in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

Everything I see about WebHelpers FileUpload is in MVC using Razor. I assume I can use this in a normal aspx page too? I installed the WebHelpers package and I see WebHelpers reference. At the top of my page I have:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="WebHelpers" %>
```

Inside my html when I place:

```
<%=FileUpload.
```

GetHTML() isn't a valid method but that's all I see in examples. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using traditional webforms, the simplest thing would be to use the [`FileUpload` web control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1" runat="server">
</asp:FileUpload>
```

If you're not interested in using that, there are many other "file upload" type controls out there (for free, and commercially).

It's my understanding that WebHelpers are used with Razor views, and I don't think it would be easy to integrate it into your webforms aspx pages (although this article seems to have a sort of hacky way of doing it: [Using Web Pages Helpers in ASP.NET Web Forms](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/162/Using-Web-Pages-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-Web-Forms)).

Comment: Oh bummer. One of the main benefits I liked was the ability to dynamically be able to specify a dynamic amount of files to upload. Do you know of any good free file upload controls that allow this? Specifically anything available via NuGet?

Comment: @user441521 The [AJAX Control Toolkit FileUpload control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ajaxFileUpload/ajaxFileUpload.aspx) is pretty robust, and offers multiple file uploads. The AJAX Control Toolkit *is* [available via NuGet](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/).